# How to create videos from images with php?

Tags: php, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-processing

Let's say I have 10 images and I want to combine those images in a video like a slideshow.

For example I want to show each image for 5 seconds and then continue with next image for another 5 seconds.

If it's possible, it will be perfect to include music and some descriptive text too.

Is there a sample code for this may be with ffmpeg library ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My first thought was to shell out to the ffmpeg command with something like this.

> Creating a Video from Images
>
> ffmpeg can be used to stitch several images together into a video.
>   There are many options, but the following example should be enough to
>   get started. It takes all images that have filenames of
>   XXXXX.morph.jpg, where X is numerical, and creates a video called
>   "output.mp4". The qscale option specifies the picture quality (1 is
>   the highest, and 32 is the lowest), and the "-r" option is used to
>   specify the number of frames per second.
>
> ffmpeg -r 25 -qscale 2 -i %05d.morph.jpg output.mp4
>
> (The website that this blurb was taken from is gone. Link
>   has been removed.)

Where 25 means 25 images per second. You could set this to 1 for a slight (1 sec) delay or use decimals, IE: 0.5 for a 2 second delay.

You can then combine a video and audio stream with something like this.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k final.mp4
```

Of course choose your appropriate codecs. If you want an mp4 use libx264 for video and aac (built into ffmpeg and no longer "experimental") for audio.

Just remember that if you choose to use a method like this that ffmpeg output goes, by default, to stderr for when you try to read it. It can be redirected to stdout if you prefer.

Comment: ok, so we can choose frame per second but is that means we can determine to duration of video by raising fps ? for example if 25 fps is 1 second. Is using `ffmpeg -r 250` means 10 second for each image ?

Comment: No, it will use 25 images per second. 25 was just copy/paste example. Try setting it to 1 or even 0.5 for a 2 second pause. I added this info to the post as well.

Comment: @AdilMalik I removed the link, which was really just to provide a source for the content. The post still contains the relevant info to accomplish the task. Also made some minor content updates since this was a bit outdated.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing that came to mind for me was [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).  I've used it with PHP for a lot of image manipulation and I know it supports reading a decent amount of video formats and according to that link it supports writing to some too.

Comment: imagick requires ffmpeg so basically there is no advantage in using that for video manipulation with php...

Answer (score 5):

yes, ffmpeg is the right solution for you. i just recently made something similar - a video site with animated thumbnails. i used ffmpeg to put together images in an aminated gif. however, the output can be whatever you need... unfortunately, in my searches into this topic i have not found any sample code that would combine all the points you are after, so i suppose you will have to try manually with ffmpeg... in my project i used php video toolkit http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvideotoolkit/ in some parts to make it a bit easier...

Answer (score 3):

You can use blend effect with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 4.jpg \
-c:v libx264 \
-filter_complex " \
[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; \
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

You should check bellow link for more effect of ffmpeg :D

https://github.com/letungit90/ffmpeg_memo